# Sonar coding rule for use of alert()

Tags: javascript, xpath, code-analysis, sonarqube, abstract-syntax-tree

We're using Sonar 3.4.1 to analyse our JavaScript on our continuous integration server.

I've added a lot of custom rules; for example: issuing blocking violations if any of the `console.*` debugging functions are used.

An example XPath query:

```
//callExpression/memberExpression[count(*) = 3 and primaryExpression[@tokenValue = "console"] and identifierName[@tokenValue = "log"]]
```

I want to add a rule for the usage of `alert(...)` but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I've tried a lot of variations on the XPath query, like for example:

```
//callExpression/memberExpression[count(*) = 2 and primaryExpression[@tokenValue = "alert"]]
```

The best I can manage to get is that `alert()`s are discovered but stuff like [`$varName.alert()`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts) is also, which is a false positive.

How can I query the usage of `alert()` on its own?

And any resources on ASTs (Abstract Syntax Trees) would be helpful so I can figure this out in future for other rules. (Teach a man to fish and all that...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following simple XPath expression works for me:

```
//primaryExpression[@tokenValue = "alert"]
```

Comment: Don't you know, where one can find an extended collection of XPathes / inspections for Sonar? (e.g., JS inspections from JetBrains products or jshint/eslint collection of rules?)